# Can I configure "Format Document" support for HTML5 tags in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, formatting, code-formatting

I frequently use the Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document command (Ctrl-K, D) in VS2010 when editing HTML markup.

I'm working on a site that uses HTML5 structural elements (`<nav>, <header>, <footer` and so on) - but I can't get Visual Studio to indent the tags' content when reformatting the document.

I've explored the options under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting -> Tag Specific Options, and explicitly added the HTML5 elements I'm using to the "Client HTML Tags" section

[image: Visual Studio 2010 options screenshot]

but this doesn't indent the tag content when reformatting.

Is this unsupported? A known bug? Some sort of configuration setting I've missed?

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Comment: Yep - upgraded to SP1 yesterday but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the validation target to HTML5.

[image]

more info: http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/3217/HTML5_Improvements_with_the_ASP.NET_MVC_3_Tools_Update.aspx